# input value on keyup (codepen)

Tags: javascript, input, codepen

I have an issue on this codepen https://codepen.io/Kimple/pen/MWEBGZy?editors=0011

In the function `titleCheck()`, I want to get the value of `<input type="text" id="title" placeholder="title">`
But I always get an empty value, and I don't know why.

I tried the same code on JSFIDDLE and had the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

You saved the value into the variable when initialized, therefore when the input is empty. The value does not update itself automatically. You need to ask for it with every key press. This way it should log the correct value:

```
 function titleCheck() {
        title.addEventListener('keyup', (event) => {
            console.log(title.value) // ask for the value every time to see it updating
            titleValue = title.value
            if (titleValue != '') {
                checkBox.checked = true;
                checkboxCheck();
            } else {
                checkBox.checked = false;
                checkboxCheck();
            }
        })
    }
    titleCheck()
```

Also next time try using snippets in your answer instead of link to codepen or other external editor.

Comment: Thx for the advice !
And ok for using snippets, I'll remember it next time.

Answer (score 0):

You have to reassign titleValue, because you set it to empty on beginning and don't change it afterwards

```
   function titleCheck() {
        title.addEventListener('keyup', (event) => {
            titleValue = document.getElementById("title").value
            console.log(titleValue)
            if (titleValue != '') {
                checkBox.checked = true;
                checkboxCheck();
            } else {
                checkBox.checked = false;
                checkboxCheck();
            }
        })
    }
```

Comment: Oh ok, thx for the advice !